# Writing decimal precision 0 but include decimal point

Tags: python, decimal, precision, f-string

I need to write a decimal with 0/zero precision, but I want it to include the decimal point. I am using f-strings.

This is what I have tried:

```
test = f"{8:3.0f}"
print(test)
Out   8
```

As well as just doing:

```
test = f"{8:3.0f}" + "."
print(test)
Out   8.
```

And

```
test = f"{8:2.0f}" + "."
print(test)
Out  8.
```

The last is what I want, but I want the decimal point "." to be included as one of the 3 characters as this is a format specific issue. So when the code is read, it reads a 3 size float that is ' 8.'

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So what's the issue? You have posted two other ways of getting the desired output, so what's the question here?

Comment: @AmitAmola The problem is that those methods were giving strings as outputs and probably desired output is float

Comment: You won't get an output to `print` as a float @Igorsharm. The `print` function automatically type casts ALL objects to strings. You can pass a float but regardless it will end up as a `str`. This is basically how pythons print [is implemented](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/ed43c2dc0a42843bbf9637b14a2c30dfe2785295/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_io.py?at=default#cl-78).

Comment: I got it. Let me try.

Comment: It would be shorter, look better, and perhaps be more clear if you included the decimal point in the f-string rather than appending it later: `test = f"{8:2.0f}."`